# Console versus Web Razor App SQLite usage

Tags: razor, web-applications, visual-studio-2019, system.data.sqlite

I'm writing a web version of a mobile app I created in Android Studio using a selection of static and dynamic tables in SQLite.

I can easily connect and access the DB using a console app, but I can see there are major differences compared to the Razor app. I assume since Razor is a client side app, I need someway to get the data copied to the virtual? space on the client side and then attach. Also, since I want each user to have a unique copy of the database how can I make it persistent on the client side if they decide to re-run the app and change the solution?

**Working Console example:**

```
 static SQLiteConnection CreateConnection()
    {

        SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn;
        // Create a new database connection:
        sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=bidb.db; Version = 3");
       // Open the connection:
     try
        {
            sqlite_conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        var a = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        return sqlite_conn;
    }
```

Comment: At this point I think I may have found the key
https://github.com/sql-js/sql.js

Comment: Now I find a perfect example including client side sqlite db in action.
Dissect, analyze, build.
https://github.com/technicalbundle/blazorservercrudefsqlite